# Do I need a transit tansit visa for UK to change terminals at LHR?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, lhr, airport-terminals

I am Chinese, living in France, holding a French 10-year residence permit. 
I traveled from France to China on a British Airways flight. I'm in transit at Heathrow. I will arrive at Terminal 5 at 20H45 and need to transfer to China at Terminal 2 at 22H40.
 I wonder if this trip is considered a "direct airside transit visa" or a "transit visitor visa"? I don't know if I need to go through border control?
Also, is 1 hour and 55 minutes enough for security check and terminal change?
I booked both France to London and London to China on one ticket

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you booked the France-to-London and London-to-China flights together on one ticket or did you book 2 separate flights on 2 separate tickets?

Comment: i have booked the France-to-London and London-to-China flights together on one ticket

Comment: If your trip is booked as one ticket (one PNR) it means the airline(s) consider the transfer times are do-able and you will not need to clear Immigration in LHR as you will transit airside. You can check if you need an airside transit visa using the link in the duplicate question

Comment: I made some educated guesses about your flights (arriving on BA327 and departing on CA850), and plugged those into the [Heathrow Connecting Flights page](https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights). The results indicate that as long as the arriving flight is on-time your connection should be fine as it's only expected to require 90 mins, while you have 115 mins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wonder if this trip is considered a "direct airside transit visa" or a "transit visitor visa"? I don't know if I need to go through border control?

Comment: @vivisong you say you have a 10-year French residence permit. Is this in the common residence permit format (bluish pink credit card form)? If so, you are likely exempt from the transit visa requirement. You could even go through immigration in transit, if necessary, if you qualify based on the residence permit.